# Does the coder we select significantly affect performance?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm having trouble understanding the purpose of "coders". My understanding is that we choose coders in order to "teach" dataflow how a particular object should be encoded in byte format and how equality and hash code should be evaluated.

By default, and perhaps by mistake, I tend to put the words " implement serializable" on almost all my custom classes. This has the advantage the dataflow tends not to complain. However, because some of these classes are huge objects, I'm wondering if the performance suffers, and instead I should implement a custom coder in which I specify exactly which one or two fields can be used to determine equality and hash code etc. Does this make sense? Put another way, does creating a custom coder (which may only use one or two small primitive fields) instead of the default serial coder improve performance for very large classes?

Answer (score 2):

Java serialization is very slow compared to other forms of encoding, and can definitely cause performance problems.  However, only serializing part of your object means that the rest of the object will be dropped when it is sent between processes.

Much better that using Serializable, and pretty much just as easy, you can use [AvroCoder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/AvroCoder.java) by annotation your classes with

```
@DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
```

This will automatically deduce an Avro schema from your class.  Note that this does not work for generic types, so you'll likely want to use a custom coder in that case.